# Hessian of norm cubed

Tags: calculus

I want to compute the Hessian of the function $f(s)= \frac{1}{3}\lVert s \rVert^3, s \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I know the gradient is $\nabla f(s)= \lVert s \rVert s$ and I read that the Hessian should be something like $\operatorname{Hess}f(s)=\lVert s \rVert I +s \frac{s^T}{\lVert s \rVert}$. However I am not sure how to compute the hessian? And how would I compute it from the from the gradient? Moreover how does the transpose of s appear in the calculation? I understand it must be there in order for the Hessian to be of the correct form.

Comment: What have you tried ? You can for instance find some answer in this site that deals with the norm of a vector and draw some analogies.

Comment: I have tried just starting with the gradient, computing the derivative of the gradient, using product rule and that the $\frac{d}{ds} (\lVert s \rVert) =\frac{s}{\lVert s \rVert}$. However I dont see how to get the transpose?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the gradient
$$\mathbf{g}=\|\mathbf{s}\| \mathbf{s}$$
and using product rule, the differential writes
$$d\mathbf{g}=(d\|\mathbf{s}\|) \mathbf{s}+\|\mathbf{s}\| d\mathbf{s}$$
The first term can be written
$d\|\mathbf{s}\|= \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{s} \|} \mathbf{s}^T d\mathbf{s}$.

Putting things together
$$d\mathbf{g}=\left[\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{s} \|} \mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T 
+ \|\mathbf{s}\| \mathbf{I}  \right]d\mathbf{s}$$
The bracket term is the Hessian.

Comment: I see. Why is it so that the $d \lVert s \rVert = \frac{1}{\lVert s \rVert} s^T ds$ and not $d \lVert s \rVert = \frac{1}{\lVert s \rVert} s ds$ ?

Comment: this is a scalar...